# Session Timeout fix

Tags: php, session, timeout, session-timeout

I've created a sort of exam site where answers are input, in order to figure out the answers, the open exam page which must be logged into can remain idle for some time.

I tried implementing this line of code to increase session timeout length to an hour:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);
```

though I don't think it has worked for me.  Does this have to be done on each page that I have the code:

```
session_start()
```

Also what is the convention in ensuring a login session remains open until:
- tab close
- window close
- logout button-press
- a new URL is entered in the address bar
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this have to be done on each page

Yes. As the [PHP manual for `ini_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) states:

> The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's
>   execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.

---

Alternatively, you could "ping" your server every minute to keep the session alive (such as from an `ajax` request to a simple PHP script (something as simple as `<?php session_start(); ?>` will suffice)), or you could control the sessions yourself through a medium such as a database. [Chris Shiflett has a good blog post on this.](http://shiflett.org/articles/storing-sessions-in-a-database)